# How to uncheck all other radio buttons when one is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I customized the radio button of bootstrap. Now I am unable to select the radio button i.e. the radio button won't remain checked. I want the radio buttons to remain checked or I want to be able to select. And I also want to uncheck all other radio buttons once another radio button is selected. How can I do this in JavaScript. Here is my code of the custom design of the radio button:

```js
var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="gender"]');

radioInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var clickedName = this.name;
    // uncheck all other radio buttons
    radioInputs.forEach(function(radioInput) {
      if (radioInput.name == clickedName && radioInput != input) {
        radioInput.checked = false;
      }
    })

    // check the clicked radio button
    this.checked = true;
  });
});
```

```css
.gender-label {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(235, 164, 117);
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.gender-label:hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 108, 50);
  background-color: rgb(255, 108, 50);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gender-div input {
  display: none;
}

.gender-radio-div {
  position: relative;
}

.gender-radio-div .gender-span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
    <p class="form-label px-1 mt-3 col-12">Gender</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 gender-div d-flex">
    <div class="col-6 gender-radio-div">
      <p id="gender-male-fake-sibling" class="d-none">dfs</p>
      <label for="gender" class="gender-label" id="frist-label">
        <!-- <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="gender-radio" value="Male"> -->
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="gender-radio" value="Male" data-gender="Male">
        <span class="gender-span">Male</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 gender-radio-div">
      <p id="gender-male-fake-sibling" class="d-none">dfs</p>
      <label for="gender" class="gender-label">
        <!-- <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="gender-radio" value="Female"> -->
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="gender-radio" value="Female" data-gender="Female">
        <span class="gender-span">Female</span>
        </label> {% comment %} <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">Female</label> {% endcomment %}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting that when I select one radio button it should uncheck all other radio buttons. I was hoping if anyone could help me do this using JavaScript. Please review my code and give feedback.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

> I also want to uncheck all other radio buttons once another radio button is selected

This is what radio button groups do by default. All, you need to do is give them all the same `name`.

But, if you are trying to reset ALL radio buttons, regardless of what group they are in, then instead of turning off all the radio buttons that are NOT checked, just turn them all off and then turn back on the selected one.

```js
var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="gender"]');

radioInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // uncheck all radio buttons
            radioInputs.forEach(function(radioInput) {
              radioInput.checked = false;
            })

            // check the clicked radio button
            this.checked = true;
        });
  });
```

```css
.gender-label {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(235, 164, 117);
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.gender-label:hover {
    border-color: rgb(255, 108, 50);
    background-color: rgb(255, 108, 50);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gender-div input{
    /*display: none;*/
}

.gender-radio-div{
    position: relative;
}

.gender-radio-div .gender-span{
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
        <p class="form-label px-1 mt-3 col-12">Gender</p>                                
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 gender-div d-flex">
        <div class="col-6 gender-radio-div">
            <p id="gender-male-fake-sibling" class="d-none">dfs</p>
            <label for="gender" class="gender-label" id="frist-label">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="gender-radio" value="Male">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="gender-radio" value="Male" data-gender="Male">
                <span class="gender-span">Male</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 gender-radio-div">
            <p id="gender-male-fake-sibling" class="d-none">dfs</p>
            <label for="gender" class="gender-label">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="gender-radio" value="Female">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="gender-radio" value="Female" data-gender="Female">
                <span class="gender-span">Female</span>
            </label>
            {% comment %} <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">Female</label> {% endcomment %}
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```